# Tombstoning to clean up memory WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, memory, garbage-collection, tombstoning

after looking at several posts online about memory usage like this one http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2011/02/10/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Memory-Usage.aspx and strugglug with similar issues in my own app, I am trying to reduce the memory footprint but have been largely unsuccessful

I did notice that tombstoning the app and relauching it releases all the memory I wanted to release, so is there a way to manually tombstone the app in the background or atleast do things similar to what it does while the app is still running?

Comment: when you navigate to a previous game you are recreating a new instance of a page, your app should back out to that page and you will then reduce your leakage. try using something like nonlinearnavigate if it's not a straight forward navigation scheme.

Comment: @jaykannan did you manage to do this or did you find another way?

Answer (score 0):

Tombstoning basically restarts your app, so this is not possible in the background without the user noticing it.

Comment: The app behaves as if it's not garbage collecting at all. I was wondering if there was a way in doing what Tombstoning does because that seems to free up the memory I wanted to release.